# adding carriage return two lines above pattern

Tags: sed

I have database log file which looks like this

```
tbl
---
tmp1
col1|col2
---------
  22|  33
  32|  45
tbl
---
tmp2
col1|col2| col3
---------------
  22|  33|  123
  32|  45|  456
```

I am trying to write a sed command which find lines which begin 
with '---' and adds a carriage return two lines above. So that the
output looks like:

```
tbl
---
tmp1

col1|col2
---------
  22|  33
  32|  45

tbl
---
tmp2

col1|col2| col3
---------------
  22|  33|  123
  32|  45|  456
```

Is it possible to do this using sed?  If so how?

Comment: please add what you've tried to question.. one idea is to reverse the input using tac, then you can add newlines in forward direction, then reverse again using tac

Comment: @Sundeep that's probably the simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

#### Method 1

Reversing the input using `tac` as suggested by Sundeep makes this problem a whole lot easier:

```
tac data.txt | sed '/^----*$/ {N;a\

}' | tac | sed '2,$p'
```

#### Method 2

This is a difficult sed-only problem (at least for me). I was close, but opted for perl. sed is turing complete, so this can definitely be translated. Intuitively, I'd say this could be completed with one extra line buffer and I hope someone answers with a sed-only implementation. There were times where it simply didn't hold. There were so many weird cases that I opted for queuing the whole way through:

```perl
my @queue = ();

while (<>) {
    if (/----*/) {
        do {
            print $queue[0];
            print "\n" if scalar @queue == 2;
            shift @queue;
        } while (scalar @queue);
        print;
    } else {
        push @queue, $_;
    }
}
do print shift @queue while scalar @queue;
```

I started looking at the problem like:

```
1
0
2
1
0
```

The numbers represent offsets from the following `---*` line where `0` is the `----*` line. When the offset is `2`, print a new line.

The problem statement is clearly expressed as:
`print \n before previous line if line ~ /----*/`.

Anyway, here's the invocation / output:

```
$ perl script.pl data.txt
```

```
tbl
---
tmp1

col1|col2
---------
  22|  33
  32|  45

tbl
---
tmp2

col1|col2| col3
---------------
  22|  33|  123
  32|  45|  456
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e 'N;/---\s*$/{2!i\\' -e '};P;D' file
```

Read two lines into the pattern space and if the second line ends in `---`, insert a line above the first of the lines.

N.B. Ordinarily, this would insert an empty line at the beginning of the file but by checking if the second line is line 2 in the file this can be avoided.

This may also be written:

```
sed 'N;/---\s*$/!P;//!D;2!i\\' file
```

An alternative of the last solution is:

```
sed 'N;/---[[:space:][:cntrl:]]*$/!P;//!D;2!i\\' file
```

Comment: I get the following error `sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'`       Using gnu sed version 4.4

Comment: That does not give me an error, but it does not do anything either.  The file is returned as is.

Comment: @ironv if the file returns  unchanged then the regexp is not matching. Perhaps the file contains unseen characters i.e. there may be spaces following the `---`, see edit.

Comment: Thanks. That worked on a RHEL7 box but not on a Windows Srv 2012 VDI (where it has to run).  I am testing against same file in both places.

Comment: @ironv `\s` is just syntactic sugar for the `[:space:]` character class other *unseen* characters may be control characters which are represented by the `[:cntrl:]` character class. See edit.